# Help with subprocess.call on a Windows machine

Tags: python, trac, python-2.4

I am trying to modify a [trac](http://trac.edgewall.org) plugin that allows downloading of wiki pages to word documents. pagetodoc.py throws an exception on this line:

```
# Call the subprocess using convenience method
retval = subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stderr=errptr, stdout=outptr, close_fds = True)
```

Saying that `close_fds` is not supported on Windows. The process seems to create some temporary files in C:\Windows\Temp. I tried removing the `close_fds` parameter, but then files the subprocess writes to stay open indefinitely. An exception is then thrown when the files are written to later. This is my first time working with Python, and I am not familiar with the libraries. It is even more difficult since most people probably code on Unix machines. Any ideas how I can rework this code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`close_fds` *[**is** supported on Windows](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen)* (search for "close_fds" after that link) starting with Python 2.6 (if `stdin`/`stdout`/`stderr` are not redirected). You might consider upgrading.

From the linked doc:

> Note that on Windows, you cannot set close_fds to true and also
> redirect the standard handles by setting stdin, stdout or stderr.

So you can either `subprocess.call` with `close_fds = True` and not setting `stdin`, `stdout` or `stderr` (the default) (or setting them to `None`):

> `subprocess.call(command, shell=True, close_fds = True)`

or you `subprocess.call` with `close_fds = False`:

> `subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stderr=errptr, stdout=outptr, close_fds = False)`

or (Python >= 3.2) you let `subprocess.call` figure out the value of `close_fds` by itself:

> `subprocess.call(command, shell=True, stderr=errptr, stdout=outptr)`

Comment: I am not sure upgrading is an option, we had to downgrade to get trac working on windows : <

Comment: as of Python 2.7.9, I get ``ValueError: close_fds is not supported on Windows plateforms if you redirect stdin/stdout/stderr.`` Which might be different from the error message from the OP, but still is cast by windows plateform and suggests that if a support of ``close_fds`` is there, it's still limited.

Comment: @vaab See my update, where I'm trying to address this